# Override base method call in all subclasses without inheriting each subclass (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, virtual, overriding

for testing purposes, I need to override a specific method call, which is currently implemented in a base class.

```
 Public Overridable Function CreateFactory(Of TFactory As {IManagerFactory(Of IManager), Class})() As TFactory
```

I want to avoid having to create an inheriting class for each existing subclass of that base class (ie. CLTestableAccountManager for CLAccountManager which inherits from CLBase etc.).

```
Public Class CLTestableAccountManager
  Inherits CLAccountManager

    Public Overrides Function CreateFactory(Of TFactory As {IManagerFactory(Of IManager), Class})() As TFactory
```

While this works, it would lead to a lot of duplicated code due to the many classes this would apply to.
The method must only be overridden when used in the context of unit tests so I shouldn't really touch the base class implementation (which is virtual/overridable).

Unfortunately, I cannot simply do something like

```
Public Class CGenericBaseOverrider(Of TBase As {CLBase})
  Inherits TBase
```

to implement a generic way for overriding the method for all subclasses of CLBase.

Can anyone point me in a direction as to how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use composition instead of inheritance?

In other words, for testing purposes create a type which implements the same interface (introduce an interface if you don't have one) and delegates all the calls *apart* from `CreateFactory` to whatever production code you've got - but performs your custom behaviour for that one call.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work, perhaps my understanding of composition is lacking. The main problem is that classes inheriting from `CLBase` call the `CreateFactory` method themselves. `CreateFactory` has depenedencies, which are hard to decouple (`[Assembly]`, `RemotingConfiguration` etc) so I want to override that method to return a mocked object instead.

Comment: @urbanhusky: Oh, I see. Hmm - that's never terribly nice. It does sound like it would be worth separating `CreateFactory` from the rest of the class, so that the `CLBase` constructor took a "factory provider" or whatever...

Comment: thanks, that gave me an idea. I'm already using an IoC container so separating the `CreateFactory` functionality into a separate class would allow me to inject my mock generating class for the tests.